# How do you compare radians in a circle?

Tags: javascript

I'm thinking of a wheel of fortune type of thing where you have to check if a marker lands on a slot. Visually, we can see 0, 2pi, 4pi, etc... are in the same position. How do I check if 0 is equal to 2pi/4pi programmatically? Assuming I have the radius as well, I thought, maybe I have to convert it to cartesian coordinates first and then compare it. However, is there a better way to do this?

Edit: Also, I should make clear that the mark can land anywhere in between a slot. For example, the marker could be anywhere in between 0 to pi/6.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
var smallestEquivalentValueInRadians = originalValueInRadians % (2 * Math.PI);
```

If you want to compare, you can do:

```
a % (2 * Math.PI) === b % (2 * Math.PI)
```

`%` is the modulo operator, basically it subtracts the second operand from the first, as many times as it can (assuming you are dealing with positive numbers).

To cater for negative values:

```
function normalizeRadian(a) {
  var circle = Math.PI * 2;
  a = a % circle;
  if (a < 0) {
    a += circle;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Also when comparing floats, it's a good idea to have some "fuzzyness", since opperations on them can be imprecise.

```
function fuzzyEqual(a, b) {
  var fuzz = 0.001;
  return a < b + fuzz && a > b - fuzz;
}
```

So the complete solution is:

```
function fuzzyEqualRadians(a, b) {
  return fuzzyEqual(normalizeRadian(a), normalizeRadian(b));
}
```

Comment: I can't understand why % 2??

Comment: I'm not sure if my question was written poorly, but this doesn't work. `(0*Math.PI) %2 === (2*Math.PI) %2` is `false`

Comment: You are making me open wikipedia :) Sorry it's (2*Math.PI), instead of 2

Comment: The code might be clearer using `var PI = Math.PI`.:-)

Comment: *fuzzyCompare* doesn't hint at what the outcome means, *fuzzyEquals* or *nearlyEquals* might suit (e.g. `==` and *Abstract **Equality** Comparison*).

Comment: I don't really understand this concept of "fuzz". It just seems like noise that would make comparisons inaccurate. Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm compensating for the fact that floats are already inaccurate. Probably not the best example, but `0.3333333333333333 * 3 === 1`

Comment: Or `Math.sqrt(2) * Math.sqrt(2) === 2.0000000000000004`